# Modify return property value of mock object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I've come across a problem when writing a unit test where in the method I'm calling it doesn't modify the mock object I've passed in. I'm not sure if there's just something obvious I'm missing?

I've setup the mock as follows:

```
var mockList = new List<Mock<IDocument>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    var mockDocument = new Mock<IDocument>();
        mockDocument.Setup(t => t.DocumentNo).Returns(i.ToString()); 
        mockList.Add(mockDocument);
}

mockDocumentRepository.Setup(x => x.GetDocuments(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(mockList.Select(m => m.Object).ToList());
```

In the executed method, if I attempt to modify another property on the mocked class (for example t.DocumentName) the value remains `Null`. Is there anyway to setup that property to accept a modification?

The reason I'm doing this is to test whether the collection of documents has been modified by another collection in the method. Not sure if there's better way's of doing this?

Comment: Is `IDocumentList` in the first line a typo for `IDocument`?

Comment: Yes, sorry! Corrected that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moq will leave all methods unimplemented unless instructed to do otherwise, and that includes properties. If you use `mockDocument.SetupProperty(doc => doc.DocumentName);` it will implement the property as a regular auto-property. You can use `mockDocument.SetupAllProperties()` if you want all properties to be auto-implemented, but you'll still have to do it for every mock object.

You could also consider making a stub instead of a mock:

```
public class StubDocument : IDocument
{
    public string DocumentNo { get; set; }
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In general, I find that stubbing is often preferable to mocking when dealing with very simple interfaces, as seems to be the case with your `IDocument`.

Comment: Boom! Thanks, working like I want it to now (in hindsight I should have just gone to http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart, that explains the SetUpProperty method).